# UDP Socket Programming - Printing the data twice

Tags: c, sockets, udp

When I call the recvfrom() for the 2nd time. It is printing both what it has received 1st and 2nd

**recvfrom() 1st time :** It is a handshake

```
if ((recvMsgSize = recvfrom(sock,  recBuffer, MAXSIZE, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &cliAddrLen)) < 0)
    DieWithError("recvfrom() failed") ;

printf("Received:");
for(i = 0; recBuffer[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    printf("%c",recBuffer[i]);
printf("\n");

/* Send response datagram back to the client */
unsigned char respBuffer[] = {255, 255, 255, 255, 4, 'Y', 'E', 'S'};
if (sendto(sock,  respBuffer, sizeof(respBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) & clntAddr, sizeof(clntAddr)) < 0)
    DieWithError("sendto() failed");
```

**recvfrom() 2nd time:**

```
if ((recvMsgSize = recvfrom(sock,  rxBuf, RX_BUF_SIZE, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &cliAddrLen)) < 0)
    DieWithError("recvfrom() failed") ;

    printf("Received Query:");
    for(j = 0; rxBuf[j] != '\0'; ++j)
        printf("%c",rxBuf[j]);
    printf("\n");
```

**OutPut:**
Received: SNK?
Received Query: SNK?
Received Query: Some data!

PS: Client is sending SNK? only once. It works fine.

I have tried to clear the buffer with `memset()` and `fflush()`. But it is still printing the both.
Someone help me to get rid of this problem.

Thank you

Comment: There's no chance `MAXSIZE` has a comma in it's `#define`, is there?  That could accidentally define the `MSG_PEEK` flag...

Comment: Check for `recvMsgSize !=0`. Also `rxBuf` would contain data of `recvMsgSize` not upto `'\0'`.